# Let $X$ be complete and $... \subset A_2 \subset A_1$ a sequence of subsets of $X$.Show that the intersection of the sets contain only one point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $ A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \ldots$ a descending sequence of non-empty subsets of $X$ whose diameters $d(A_n) \to 0$. Show that the intersection of the sets contain only one point.

Let $x,y \in \bigcap A_n$. Now $d(x,y) \leqslant d(A_n) \to 0$ so $x = y$. So if there is a point in the intersection there must be only one. I'm stuck on how to show that there is even this one point? What can I do to show this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $X$ is complete? (Either way, I think this is probably false -- I assume that $X = [0,1]$ counts, and we have a counterexample where $A_k = (0, 1/k)$.)

Comment: You want to assume that $A_k$ is compact, I guess. Otherwise you have counterexamples like the one of Mees de Vries.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem. EDIT: Actually, your exact statement is proven in the "variant in complete metric spaces" section of the Wikipedia article.  PS: Hallo @Severin 

Answer (score 1):

You need the $A_n$ to be closed, or else $A_n=(0,\frac1n)$ would be in a counterexample in $\Bbb R$.

Pick $a_n \in A_n$ arbitrarily, show $(a_n)_n$ is Cauchy because $d(A_n) \to 0$ and so there is a limit $a \in X$. By closedness and nestedness $a \in A_n$ for every $n$.

Comment: By closedness and nestedness what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @Simeon the fact that all $A_n$ are closed and $A_n \subseteq A_m$ if $n \ge m$.